# send data from background.js to popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my `background.js`, it had ajax loaded when a URL is matched during the on-load. For instance, it's google.com and it fire an ajax and recieved some data. But how to send those data to my popup.html?

I tried `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` but I don't get it. The param send to which file?

I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

when you send data via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, you will be able to get it in your popup by listening to `onMessage` events.

when you send a message from background.js like this,

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'hello there'});
```

you can get it in a js file loaded by popup.html:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, messageSender, sendResponse) {
    // message is the message you sent, probably an object
    // messageSender is an object that contains info about the context that sent the message
    // sendResponse is a function to run when you have a response
});
```

See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I tried that but it didn't work. I put this chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}) into my bg.js and this 
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      alert('yes');
  }); into the popup.html (I use include actually) but nothing happened when I clicked the popup.

Comment: that is probably because when you send the message from background, your popup is close, so no one is catching the message. When you open the popup, it is listening, but the message was already sent. But you can do this the opposite way. Both the popup and background script can send and listen to messages the same way. When you open the popup, send a message to background, and in the background, listen to this message and send a message when you get it. This time your popup should catch the message.

Comment: because I do not want any delay when user see the popup. If I do the reverse way, will it delay? because in my bg.js, I do ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your question to include your manifest.json? That's often very helpful when making suggestions.

Assuming that your popup.html is part of a content script, you need to use [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) to send messages from the background page to content scripts.

Also consider using [chromeps](https://github.com/anderspitman/chromeps) for simple pubsub style message propagation throughout your extension without having to worry about when to use `chrome.runtime` vs `chrome.tabs`.