# Chrome Extensions: Passing message by button from popup.html to event page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup, message-passing

I would like to open a new tab from within my popup.html by clicking a button contained in popup.html.

My approach is to send a message from popup.html to the eventPage.js which will then open the new tab when the message is received.

This however is not working. Please see the code below:

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="width:400px;">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="openTab"><button type="button" id="btnOpenTab" name="btnOpenTab" onclick="sendMessage()">Open New Tab</button></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**eventPage.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    { 
        if (request.action == "openNewTab")
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.url });
    }
);
```

**popup.js**

```
function sendMessage()
                {
                    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
                        action: "openNewTab",
                        url: "www.google.com"
                    });
                }
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Open new tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Opens new tab",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

EDIT: Found an error message in console with this message:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content security policy prevents you using JavaScript in your HTML (in this case, you are getting an error because of the `onclick="sendMessage()"` in your `popup.html` file.

You can get the desired result by removing the `onclick` attribute from the button and instead adding the event listener in your `popup.js` file:

```
document.getElementById('btnOpenTab').onclick = sendMessage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that you cannot use "onclick" or inline javascript in chrome extensions. Must use a linked js file in header and use event listeners to handle click events.

Answer (score 1):

remove `onclick="sendMessage()"` and write this in **popup.js**

```
function sendMessage(){
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        action: "openNewTab",
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609195/send-data-from-background-js-to-popup-html"
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('btnOpenTab');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        sendMessage();
    });
});
```