# Chrome Extension to open URL in another window in Incognito mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am from Siebel developer background. Dont have exposure/any kind of work experience with web development/chrome.extensions. For one of the requirement I need to open multiple sieble sessions on clicking a custom button in the application. There is limitation that multiple sessions can't be supported with current siebel product version we are using.

Hence trying to leverage the chrome extension option over here. With the other stackoverflow postings, have created a basic extension. Below are the manifest.json and eventPage.js files.

```js
{
  "name": "Open new window",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Opens new window",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title":"Message!"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

```js
eventPage.js
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    { 
        if (request.action == "openNewTab")
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.url, "incognito": true});
    }
);
```

From the Siebel application, trying to call chrome.extension, but running into issues. Below is calling script.

```js
$("#siebelUIButton").click(function sendMessage()
{
 chrome.extension.sendMessage({
  action: "openNewTab",
  url: "www.google.com"
 });
});
```

I am sure that code written doesn't makes sense, requesting your help and guidance to overcome the issue.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: If "Siebel application" is a web page app, not an extension, then you need to allow the web URL to send messages to your extension in manifest.json: [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

Comment: You cannot do that, the *Siebel application* doesn't have access to `chrome.extension.sendMessage`

Comment: Ah, in addition to externally_connectable, you need to use chrome.runtime instead of chrome.extension.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, for checking on it. As suggested i updated the manifest.json to include externally_connectable and used chrome.runtime.sendMessage from contentscript and in the background.js chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener. No luck so far, no error but response is coming as undefined.

Comment: content script:$("#siebuibutton").click(function(){
var extnId = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extnId, {action: "openNewTab",
  url: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609195/send-data-from-background-js-to-popup-html"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
  //this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
    });

});

Comment: background.js:   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse)
        { 
            if (request.action == "openNewTab")
                chrome.windows.create({ url: request.url, "incognito": true});
        }
    );

Comment: Make sure to use the real id, not aaaaaa. Also the listener should be onMessageExternal, see the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow the question.  Sounds like you want to open a URL from a background script into a new tab.  You can call this from a content script (no need for a background script).  This will open the URL into a tab from the content script.  Where URL is your http:// URL string, where rptTab is open same browser tab when this 'button' is selected...

```
var win = window.open(url, 'rptTab');
```